# I have a form in drupal 7 how to submit the results to database to create new user

Tags: php, forms, drupal-7

I had a question about a tutorial that I saw on sitepoint.com
http://www.sitepoint.com/building-multi-page-wizard-like-form-drupal/

I've got everything in the custom module and now I need to know how to go about actually creating the user using this form.

There's a multipageform_form1_submit code where it says //Store the values from $finalformvalues in database or file etc

What am I to do to actually create a new user? I'm sure there's a little snippet of code that needs to get added but I have looked and looked and cannot seem to find what I need. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To add a new user, just use the user functions in your hook submit. See this [article](https://www.drupal.org/node/1063598) for code examples.